# IMG doesnt show up but correct path etc

Tags: html, css

My logo doesn't show up even though I have no errors in the tag and or the path. I created a new container for my logo so I can place it anywhere, but even without it doesn't want to pop up.

Here is my code. The IMG which doesn't show is in the first Container after the body tag in my html file.

```css
body{
    background-color: #EFFFEA;
    }
.rslides {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75%;
  height: 87%;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  }
.rslides li {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }
.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }
.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
#news {
    background-color: red;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 87.5%;
    left: 12.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
    }
#standort {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 87.5%;
    left: 37.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
    }
#öffnungszeiten {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 87.5%;
    left: 62.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
    }
/* Padding regelt die Größe von Nav und Footer */
#logo{
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
   }
#footer-wrapper {
    background-color: #6EA556;
    position:absolute;
    width: 75%;
    top: 120%;
    left: 12.5%;
    font-size: 85%;
    }
nav {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    top:0%;
    left:12.5%;
    opacity: 0.85; 
    }
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    }
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:table-cell;  
    padding:15px 30px 15px 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: black;
    }
footer ul li a{
    color: #F6FAF3;
    }
ul li a:hover {
    color:grey;
    }
address{
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Facharbeitsgruppe Alex,Joshua,Karl,Moritz">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="bio.ico">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Naturkostladen Häcklingen</title>
<meta name="description" content="Naturkostladen H&auml;cklingen-L&uuml;neburg, Ihr freundlicher Frischespezialist f&uuml;r K&auml;se, Antipasti, Backwaren, Obst und Gem&uuml;se..Qualit&auml;t seit 1998">
<meta name="keywords" content="Naturkostladen H&auml;cklingen,Biomarkt,Bioladen,L&uuml;neburg,Bio,Demeter,Bioland,Naturland">
<meta name="editor" content="Visual Studio Code">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\stylemain.css">
    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.js"></script>  
    
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      speed: 1500,
      timeout: 8000,
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="rslides">
  <li><img src="bilder/IMG_4819.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Ein Holzstapel hinter Stroh im Eingangsbereich"></img></li> 
  <li><img src="bilder/Bank.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Unsere Schöne Bank vor dem Eingangsbereich"></img></li>
  <li><img src="bilder/Kartoffeln.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Ein Mitarbeiten an der Gemüse Theke"></img></li> 
</ul> 

<div id="logo"><img src="/bilder/Scan_Pic0005.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Unser Logo"></img>
</div>
  


<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 
<div id="news"></div>
<div id="standort"></div>
<div id="öffnungszeiten"></div>

<footer id="footer-wrapper">
    
    <ul>
       <li><a>Irgendwas</a></li>
       <li><a>Impressum</a></li>
       <li><a><address>Erstellt von</address></a></li>
       
      
    </ul>  
   

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go to developer tools, then to the network tab. Look at what resource is loading, what the request and response headers are.

Comment: `"/bilder/Scan_Pic0005.jpg"` is absolute path, means that your image is in bilder folder that in root folder, another images like `"bilder/IMG_4819.jpg"` is in relative path, means in bilder folder in the same place your page in 
http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/

Comment: Just Add below css
body{
    min-height: 100%;
}

Comment: Ye Al-Molthafar was right thx ^^ Didnt noticed that.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar i suggest you expand this to an answer as you were correct, to close the question for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about the way to write the URL of `src` of your `img` tag, you have 2 ways to write paths; absolute path and relative path.

In your code :

`src="/bilder/Scan_Pic0005.jpg"` is absolute path, means that your image is in bilder folder that in root folder in your host or domain or application (depends on application server or your project).

Another images like `src="bilder/IMG_4819.jpg"` is in relative path, means in bilder folder in the same place your page that shows that image as example bilder folder is sibling of index.html if your code was in index.html

For more about paths in HTML visit this link: http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute